# What solutions are there to backup millions of image files and sub-directories on a webserver efficiently?

Tags: linux, ftp, compression, backup, subdirectory

I have a website that I host on a Linux VPS which has been growing over the years. One of its primary functions is to store images/photos and these image files are typically around 20-40kB each. The way the site is organised at the moment is all images are stored in a root folder ‘photos’ and under that root folder are many subfolders determined by a random filename. For example, one image could have a file name abcdef1234.jpg and that would be stored in the folder photos/ab/cd/ef/. The advantage of this is that there are no directories with excessive numbers of images in them and accessing files is quick. However, the entire photos directory is huge and is set to grow. I currently have almost half a million photos in tens of thousands of sub-folders and whilst the system works fine, it is fairly cumbersome to back up. I need advice on what I could do to make life easier for back-ups. At the moment, I am backing up the entire photos directory each time and I do that by compressing the folder and downloading it. It takes a while and puts some strain on the server. I do this because every FTP client I use takes ages to sift through all the files and find the most recent ones by date. Also, I would like to be able to restore the entire photo set quickly in the event of a catastrophic webserver failure so even if I could back up the data recursively, how cumbersome would it be to have to upload each back stage by stage?

Does anyone have any suggestions perhaps from experience? I am not a webserver administrator and my experience of Linux is very limited. I have also looked into CDN’s and Amazon S3 but this would require a great deal of change to my site in order to make these system work – perhaps I’ll use something like this in the future.

Comment: First off, you shouldn't be "compressing the folder".  The image files are all already compressed, I would have to presume, and so running a compressor on them will not provide any gain, but will stress your server with many wasted CPU cycles.

Comment: The only reason I compress the folder is to make it easier to download through FTP otherwise it takes forever!

Comment: If you mean bundling a bunch a files into a single archive file, you can do that without compressing or trying to compress.

Comment: I'm not very clued up with Linux. Are you able to share briefly how I'd do that so that I can try it? Thx

Comment: On linux, just use tar.  Do man tar to see how it works.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment and selecting the newest files for each back up. Bit time consuming but it works. Will be painful to have to upload all the backups though in the event of a failure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated that you run a VPS, I assume you have shell access which gives you substantially more flexibility (as opposed to a shared webhosting plan where you can only interact with a web frontend and an FTP client). I'm pretty sure that [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) is specifically designed to do what you need to do (sync large numbers of files between machines, and do so efficiently).

This gets into Superuser territory, so you might get more advice over on that forum.

Comment: Hi, yes I have shell access and I'll look into that thanks. I have heard of rsync but not really given it much attention yet. Thx.